# How to get wrapping div to "hug" svg elements?

Tags: css, svg

This question refers to the situation shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9pq7/).

As you can see, currently, the `div` (aka `.svg-container`; orange background) that contains the `svg` elements (white background) is about 70px wider than it needs to be.  Can I get this div to "shrink-to-fit" its contents using *no* JS?

EDIT: Just to be clear, the shape and positioning of the remaining elements should remain unaffected by the change.  The only thing that should change is the shape `.svg-container`, and this should be in a way that the orange fringe along its right side has the same width as it has along the three other sides.  The final result should *look* like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eerLa/).  (Of course, to produce this second jsFiddle, I had to explicitly set the width of `.svg-container`, which is not the kind of solution I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the CSS that would translate into "extend beyond content's right edge the same amount as that beyond other three edges.")

---

And now, the obligatory source code:

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  font-family:consolas,monaco,courier,monospace;
}

.centered{
  max-width:280px;
  background-color:red;
  padding:15px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  color:#8f8;
  background-color:#333;
}
table td:first-child{
  width:75px;
}
.svg-container{
  line-height:0;
  background-color:orange;
}
svg{
  margin:1px;
}
rect {
  shape-rendering:crispEdges;
  stroke:none;
  fill:white;
}
td{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```
<div class="centered">
  <div class="content">
    <table><tr>
      <td>
        <div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam elementum, lectus ut consectetur mattis,</p></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="svg-container">
          <svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg><svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg><svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg><svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg><svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg><svg width="50" height="50"><rect width="50" height="50"></rect></svg>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr></table>

  </div> <!-- .content -->
</div> <!-- .centered -->
```

Comment: Divs will always expand to fit their parent unless a width is set. In this instance, you can set `width=50` on the containing `td` or set `width: 50px` on `.svg-container`.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this answered on SO before.  Don't have the why, but there's nothing you can do here.  It works as you're expecting if you remove enough SVGs that they no longer wrap:  http://jsfiddle.net/P9pq7/2/

Comment: Are you looking for the background color to display or using for debug purposes?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved if you add `float: left` to the svg(s) then `overflow: hidden` to the container (so the background shows), then finally, and the key to it all, add `clear:both` to the `:nth-child(odd)` selector to clear every 2nd svg from the float.

```
/* Stuff I've added to your CSS */

.svg-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
svg {
    float: left;
}
svg:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/eerLa/7/**

Comment: Or add a clearfix instead of `overflow: hidden`. (Both are hideous float-hacks, but I like clearfix better.)

Comment: @Rudie or use `float:left` on the container.  But I don't see overflow or clearfix as hacks.

Comment: All float stuff is hacks. This is never how float was meant to be used (for layouting), but that's a story for another day. I tried `float: left`, but the column didn't shrink... Weird. Maybe Chrome?

Comment: Oooh floats on the children. Yes, of course! =) And 0 line-height is clever.

Comment: @Rudie I can't take any credit for the 0 line-height, the OP had that already.

Comment: Haha you could have! I missed that. Still clever. Stealin' it!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
I just noticed your final result fiddle.

***Option 1***

Here's one option that feels pretty hacky: http://jsfiddle.net/P9pq7/7/
Change `.svg-container` to a span with no style. Add `border: 1px solid orange; margin-top: -6px;` to `svg` and `margin-top: 0` to `svg:first-child` - works in FF, Chrome, and Safari

OR

***Option 2 (better than option 1)***

http://jsfiddle.net/eerLa/5/: Creates a table within your td using css

Use these styles:

```
.svg-container {
    line-height:0;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
svg {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

OR

**Option 3 (if you don't like tables)**

http://jsfiddle.net/P9pq7/10/

```
.svg-container {
    line-height:0;
    font-size: 0;
}
svg {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px;
    background: orange;
}
svg:nth-child(even) {
    clear: right;
}
```

**original answer**

Without setting explicit width on the containing div or td, you can set `clear: both; display: block` on `svg` to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/P9pq7/4/

Comment: Instead of requiring a `<span>`, you could just display the div inline.

Comment: That's true. Although a span is `already display: inline`, so it's one less css declaration. Although in that instance, I suppose we could just get rid of the element altogether.

Comment: Can't remove it if it needs a background. Not sure what OP is trying to achieve though. Final result fiddle looks weird.

Comment: In option 1 in my answer, it's actually an unnecessary element.